# How to clean NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, nstextview

I need to clean NSTextView indefinite amount of times. I do this with the following code:

````
@property IBOutlet NSTextView *textView;
```
[self.textView setString:@""];
````

but this code overflows memory if used unlimited amout of times. As a shortened example, this code:

```
loop:
[self.textView setString:@""];
goto loop;
```

overflows memory very quickly.
How can I clean NSTextView unlimited number of times without overflowing the memory?

Comment: What you you trying to do? You only have to set it to `@""` once. Why would you want to do it repeatedly?

Comment: I have to set it once to clean it just one time. If I need to clean it again then I have to call it again. This "repeating" example just illustrates that this operation consumes memory and does not release it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you discovered, the following consumes memory without bound:

```
while (true) {
    self.textView.string = @"";
}
```

However, this uses a fixed amount of memory:

```
while (true) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        self.textView.string = @"";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the solution. I thought that autoreleasepool was not necessary with ARC, but I was wrong!